# Different Serial Result when reading in java and c#

Tags: java, c#, serial-communication

I have two programs that talk with serial rs232
1. written in c# with the use pf SerialPort class
2. written in java with the use of librxtx - SerialPort class

both: BaudRate - 9600, Parity-None, StopBits - 1, DataBits - 8

they communicate with the same the device that send the same data all the time

in c# i get the following 6 bytes: 255,98,144,19,1,0
in java i get the following 6 bytes: -1,98,-112,19,1,0

the c# code is the right one.

here are the code for c#:

```
m_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM15", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
m_serialPort.DataReceived += SPDataRecieved;
m_serialPort.Open();

public override void SPDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
       try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(80);
            byte[] toBytes = new byte[6];
            m_serialPort.Read(toBytes, 0, 6);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

here are the code for java:

```
m_SerialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
m_SerialPort.setSerialPortParams 
(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
InputStream in = m_SerialPort.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
int len = -1;
Thread.sleep(80);
len = in.read(buffer,0,6);
```

what i need to add to the java code that the result will be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `byte[]` in Java and C# differ for 2 main reasons:

- Java byte type is signed, while the C# byte type is unsigned (if you need signed use sbyte type)
- Java stores byte as Big Endian, while C# uses Little Endian by default

Since java doesn't include unsigned byte in the language, you can print a conversion to int in the following way:

```
byte b = 0x3a;    // random value
return b & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The java bytes are signed, while the C# bytes are not.

Convert each java value with the following:

```
newValue = (value + 256) % 256

// (-1 + 256) % 256 = 255
//  (98 + 256) % 256 = 98 etc
```